# AQL numeric literal parse error without leading zero

Tags: arangodb, aql

I get a parse error with an AQL query that includes a **numeric literal** with a value 'x' where
-1 < x < 1 and x != 0, and where the **leading zero is omitted**, such as `x < .5` or `x > -.2`.

I think this may be a bug, but the documentation doesn't clearly state whether a leading zero is required or not (seems odd that it would be required).

I'm only running version 3.4 rc4, so I can't verify if this behavior is present with any officially released versions. Can someone confirm? Or are there any ArangoDB devs on here that care to comment?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AQL does not support floating point number literals without leading digit.

The [documentation](https://docs.arangodb.com/devel/AQL/Fundamentals/DataTypes.html#string-literals) shows examples of supported notations, and one like `.5` is not among them.

If you want to propose this as feature, [create an issue on GitHub](https://github.com/arangodb/arangodb/issues/new).

You can find the code that defines the language tokens for numbers here:
https://github.com/arangodb/arangodb/blob/devel/arangod/Aql/tokens.ll#L447

```
(0|[1-9][0-9]*) {
  /* a numeric integer value */
...
(0|[1-9][0-9]*)((\.[0-9]+)?([eE][\-\+]?[0-9]+)?) {
  /* a numeric double value */
```

As can be seen from these regular expressions, literals like `00` and `00.123` are not supported either - there must not be more than one leading `0` in the integer part.

Comment: Thanks for the info! I did see the examples, but I didn't dig down into the code to see what they were doing (!). This seems a bit odd as I've not run into parsers that required a leading 0 on floats (C++/boost, javascript). I will open a ticket.

Comment: @Dale It is actually in line with the [JSON specs](http://json.org/). Valid JSON number representations are also valid number literals in AQL. Neither supports `.5`, `00`, `00.123`, hex, octal or binary notations (JavaScript does however). It would be bad to change the handling of the AQL parser to support additional notations for number literals in my opinion, while JSON handling can't be changed and the restrictions would still apply there (e.g. in bind variables).

Comment: I'm not deeply familiar with the JSON specs, but this seems like an unnecessary limitation for parsing numbers (I'm guessing just to make the parser implementation simpler). AQL isn't exactly Javascript, so there no philosophical reason to comply with the JSON spec. But I can understand if AQL relies on Javascript/JSON for it's own parsing that it may be hard to change (although both Chrome and Firefox parse floats without a leading zero).

Comment: AQL certainly borrows some language constructs from JavaScript, but it is different in many ways. How AQL is processed by the server has no connection to JavaScript / the ECMAScript standard. JSON however is the default input and output format of ArangoDB. The only other format is ArangoDB's own binary format VelocyPack. As you said, limitations allow for simpler code in parsers, and since JSON is what does in and out, it makes sense to follow the JSON specs exactly to avoid any odd differences between how number literals can be written in AQL versus what you can send to the API endpoints.

Comment: There is some work on the way to make a leading zero optional (devel branch, so for v3.5.0 if it doesn't get backported): https://github.com/arangodb/arangodb/pull/7647

Comment: Number literals documentation improved in this PR: https://github.com/arangodb/arangodb/pull/8288/files#diff-3db3fdc3e9d2a0ff417dae20bd5ec1aeR37

Answer (score 0):

Ran this in 3.3.19 and runs fine:

```
let tmp = [0.2,3,4,0.5]
for t in tmp
filter t > 0.5
return t
```

This throws a parsing error

```
let tmp = [0.2,3,4,0.5]
for t in tmp
filter t > .5
return t
```

So, I would think it is safe to say that the 0 is mandatory

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

We recently merged [a pull request](https://github.com/arangodb/arangodb/pull/7647) into the devel branch of ArangoDB that adds support for fractional numbers without leading zeros to AQL. This is available in the ArangoDB development version from next build onwards, but not available in any release yet. So far, target release would be 3.5.

If there is popular demand for the feature, it should be easy to backport the pull request to ArangoDB 3.4 as well.